# When not to use ng-cloak in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, ngcloak

One query regarding AngularJS (`ng-cloak`), as per official docs:

> The `ng-cloak` directive is used to prevent the AngularJS HTML template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the HTML template display.

Does this mean that we should always use this in the AngularJS app? Or are there any side-effects of using it all the time?

Comment: To prevent the page from loading with a flicker in the first place, you need to **resolve** the route in `angular.config`, which completely removes the need for `ng-cloak`

Answer (score 1):

This is the suggestion in the [official website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak):

> The directive can be applied to the element, but the preferred usage
>   is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page
>   to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

So for slow internet the page will be white for a while, which is definitely not a desired outcome.

Answer (score -1):

Angular provides the ng-cloak directive to try and hide the element it cloaks so that you don’t see the flash of these markup expressions when the page initially loads before Angular has a chance to render the data into the markup expressions.
Note the ng-cloak attribute on this element, which here is an outer wrapper element of the most of this large page’s content. ng-cloak is supposed to prevent displaying the content below it, until Angular has taken control and is ready to render the data into the templates.
 For more details visit :https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jun/02/AngularJs-ngcloak-Problems-on-large-Pages